# nginx returning old data after reload

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have below nginx configuration. As per my setup, nginx must serve requests from the upstream-server if that configuration exists, otherwise should just return the default page from the server block in the end.

Another external system (consul-template) dynamically generates the upstream server block, at which point nginx should stop serving the default page and should start serving the content from the actual upstream server.

My issue is that nginx does not do that for first couple of requests, but eventually will start serving traffic from upstream as expected. I suspect there is some caching going on the nginx side that I need help with.

```
http {                                                                 
      # This is a conditional block. It may or may not be present.                                       
      upstream test {                        
        server 192.168.0.7:8080;             
      }                                      
      server {                               
        server_name lvh.me;     
        listen 80;              
        listen [::]:80;         
                                
        location / {            
          proxy_pass http://test;
        }                        
      }                                                
  
  # Default server block. Catches all requests.                          
  server {                  
    server_name _;          
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
                                  
    root /var/www/localhost;      
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                                     
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;                                                                      
    expires off;                                                                                
    etag off;                                                                                   
                                                                                                
    location = /favicon.ico {                                                                   
      alias /var/www/localhost/favicon.ico;                                                     
    }                                                                                           
  }                                                                                             
}
```

Detailed Steps:

1. No upstream server present -> make a request -> default page is returned.

- (Optional) I even wait here for >30s and still the same behavior is seen, indicating that its a caching problem for sure.

2. Add upstream server -> reload nginx -> make a request -> again default page is returned. <- This is bad!!
3. Make another request -> this time the page from upstream is returned.
4. Somehow nginx did not recognize to return the right page in the second step.